# How to create a connection bar for a application in wpf mvvm pattern

Tags: wpf, connection

we need to create a application which has a pin button on title bar.
if its clicked the application should get hide on top of the desktop as like connection bar in remote desktop application.
can some one pls tell me how to do that... merely searched for 1 week but still could't find. connection bar example

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the pin button to be in the border, like the close and minimize buttons, or just as part of your app? If its just part of your app then something like this should work:

```
this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

Just toggle that based on the button click and add an 'invisible' button to the top of your app, which displays a drop-down on mouse-over.

Comment: [PLs find the connection bar in this image link, we need to create as it is][1]


  [1]: http://www.google.co.in/imgres?um=1&hl=en&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=677&tbm=isch&tbnid=Vr99HjEyDtMVQM:&imgrefurl=http://ubit.buffalo.edu/software/virtual/windows/remote-desktop.php&docid=oaansi-NCWEh-M&imgurl=http://ubit.buffalo.edu/software/virtual/images/screens/windows/view-full-screen.png&w=500&h=315&ei=7HusUKqEDsyJrAf8-YDIAw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=556&vpy=158&dur=445&hovh=178&hovw=283&tx=177&ty=75&sig=113706176561551853309&page=1&tbnh=135&tbnw=215&start=0&ndsp=24&ved=1t:429,r:2,s:0,i:75